# How to read all file content and find string in file content using C#?

Tags: c#, readfile, string-comparison

I have a list of `files` (`.aspx,.cs,.html` etc) in a `string` array.
I read all the content of a `file`. Till here is ok!

What i want to do is i want to **search** a specific string

**EG:**

```
<meta name="description" content="NOINDEX" />
<meta name="keywords" content="NOINDEX" />
```

by looping through the list of file(s) and getting file contents and check whether it `contains` the **searchstring**.

```
foreach (string item in strFiles)
                {
                    innerList = item.Split(',');
                    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(innerList[0]))
                    {
                        fileList.Add(innerList[0]);
                        fileContents = File.ReadAllText(innerList[0].Replace("\\\\","\\"));
                        //if(fileContents.Contains(""))
                        if (fileContents.IndexOf(strToSearch) != -1)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("string contains strsearch");
                        }
                    }
                }
```

above code loops through all `files` and read content of all files one by one  but, i am not able to compare/find exact string  from the file content.

Due to extra space in file content/ new line character etc.

**Sample 'fileContent' string:**

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/_masterpages/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="ChangePassword.aspx.cs" Inherits="Account_ChangePassword" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
<meta name="description" content="NOINDEX" />
<meta name="keywords" content="NOINDEX" />
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentHeaderNav" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentBody" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content4" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentToggleBox" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content5" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentBottom" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
```

**Sample 'searchString' :**

```
<meta name="description" content="NOINDEX" /><meta name="keywords" content="NOINDEX" />
```

Any suggestions please...!

Help appreciated!

Comment: The reason why you're not getting any result is, that the indexof-method also validates characters like \r\n (line breaks etc). You have to put them into your searchString aswell :)

Comment: Its better to use RegularExpressions as it could detect all variations like whitespaces, extra attributes, ...

Answer (score 1):

You can search replace using regular expressions

```
foreach (string item in strFiles)
                {
                    innerList = item.Split(',');
                    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(innerList[0]))
                    {
                        fileList.Add(innerList[0]);
                        fileContents = File.ReadAllText(innerList[0].Replace("\\\\","\\"));
                        if(Regex.IsMatch(fileContents,@"<meta[^>]*name=""description""[^>]*content=""NOINDEX""[^*]*/>\s*<meta[^>]*name=""keywords""[^>]*content=""NOINDEX""[^*]*/>"))
                           { Console.WriteLine("string contains strsearch");
}
                        }
                    }
                }
```

If you want to replace it you can use like:

```
Regex.Replace(fileContents,@"<meta[^>]*name=""description""[^>]*content=""NOINDEX""[^*]*/>\s*<meta[^>]*name=""keywords""[^>]*content=""NOINDEX""[^*]*/>", ReplacementString)
```

Comment: i have list of tags,string which is to be searched from 'filecontent' so how to match these strings/content ? I mean how to add regex for the string that is used to compare from db?

Comment: well you can use regular expressions for those too, you may make a list of regularexpressions for tags and loop searching them in content like: `MyTags.ForEach(t=>AppendResult(t));` , `public AppendResult(string x){if(Regex.IsMatch(fileContents,x))
                           { Console.WriteLine("string contains strsearch");}}`

Comment: will you please tell me the meaning of symbols used  in Regex? i am new to this... :)

Comment: @SHEKHARSHETE `[^>]*` = zero or more occurrence of anything but `>` (we want to make sure that we haven't reach the end of tag) and `\s*` =  zero or more  white space . More info: [http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/46/c-regular-expressions-cheat-sheet](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/46/c-regular-expressions-cheat-sheet) and [http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9099/The-Minute-Regex-Tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9099/The-Minute-Regex-Tutorial)

Comment: thanks for explaining symbols! one more thing i would like to tell, i have a table which defines rules i.e the list of rows which contains html tags or any string or js code which i want to search in 'filecontent' string. we add only the string eg: google analyatics code is added in rule table and this 'javascript' is to be searched in each 'filecontent' Not sure how to do???

Comment: well you can insert regularexpressions instead of string

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105114/discussion-between-shekhar-shete-and-ashkan-mobayen-khiabani).

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar not long ago when I wrote a small application to find English words hidden within other English words, and if you then remove the "inner" word from the "outer" word, if the result still was an English word (yeah, I do get bored sometimes)

The result was a small blogpost that I think is relevant to you, mainly because I'm loading a TON of files and searching them.

[Here is the blogpost](http://pedro.digitaldias.com/?p=401)

As you can see, I did use parallel execution to speed up the process, something that gave me results in less than 50ms, which in my book is acceptable :)

Hope this gives you what you need!